# "resource.adaptTo" NullPointer Unit test AEM Sling Model Java

Tags: java, junit, aem, sling

I'm doing a pretty basic Unit test for **Sling Model** in **AEM**, so, when I run the test I get the following error:

> [ERROR]   CtaModelTest.testGetText:36 NullPointer

This is my Java code, the Model is a very basic Sling AEM Model, I'm using the `@ModelAnnotation` as follow:

```java
@Model(adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class, defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL)
```

```java
package com.myproject.core.models;
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.Resource;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import com.day.cq.wcm.api.Page;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContext;
import io.wcm.testing.mock.aem.junit5.AemContextExtension;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;
import junitx.util.PrivateAccessor;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@ExtendWith(AemContextExtension.class)
class CtaModelTest {
    private static final String COMPONENT_PATH = "/content/campaigns/myproject/master/demo-campaign/demo-email";
    
    private CtaModel ctaModel;

    private Page page;
    private Resource resource;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup(AemContext context) throws Exception {
        
        context.load().json("/ctaModelTest.json", COMPONENT_PATH);
        context.addModelsForClasses(CtaModel.class);
        
        resource = context.resourceResolver().getResource(COMPONENT_PATH + "/jcr:content/par/hero/cta");
        ctaModel = resource.adaptTo(CtaModel.class);
    }

    @Test
    void testGetText() throws Exception {
        String txt = ctaModel.getText();
        assertNotNull(txt);
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to fix it?

Comment: Can you post the code of your model, as well as the JSON document you're loading into the test AEM Context? This could be a simple property name mismatch but it's difficult to say without seeing the line where the NPE occurs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that `resource.adaptTo(CtaModel.class)` returned null. The problem is, that adaptTo(...) returns null very silently, if anything fails. Therefore the SlingMocks documentation recommends `ModelFactory.createModel(...)` instead of `adaptTo(...)` for SlingModels.

https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/sling-mock.html#model-instantiation

```
// load some content into the mocked repo
context.load().json(..., "/resource1");

// load resource
Resource myResource = content.resourceResolver().getResource("/resource1");

// instantiate Sling Model (adaptable via Resource)
// this will throw exceptions if model cannot be instantiated
MyModel myModel = context.getService(ModelFactory.class).createModel(myResource, MyModel.class);
```

If you doing this, the ModelFactory will log error-details, why the Sling model couldn't be created. So you know, what the problem is, and you don't need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

If there are issues with init method, specially if any object injected like currentPage or services are null, then model will return null silently even when createModel is used.

https://myaemlearnings.blogspot.com/2020/08/unit-testing-in-aem-debugging-issues-in.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have defined  your

`defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL`

in your model's configurations. This resolved the issue for me pretty quickly

```
@Model(
    adaptables = SlingHttpServletRequest.class,
    adapters = {MyModel.class, ComponentExporter.class},
    resourceType = MyModelImpl.RESOURCE_TYPE,
    defaultInjectionStrategy = DefaultInjectionStrategy.OPTIONAL
)
@Exporter(
    name = ExporterConstants.SLING_MODEL_EXPORTER_NAME,
    extensions = ExporterConstants.SLING_MODEL_EXTENSION
)
public class MyModelnImpl extends AbstractComponentImpl implements MyModel{
```